# Feature extraction methods for a distribution as exogenous variable in regression models

Tags: regression, gamma-distribution, feature-engineering

I have age distributions for more than $m>100$ different populations, each of varying sizes $(n_1, n_2, \dots, n_m)$. I'd like to create a regression model where these age distributions are used as exogenous variables to predict outcomes $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_m)$.

Assuming that the Gamma distribution provides a fairly accurate fit for each of these population age distributions, I define $F_i$ and $f_i$ as the CDF and PDF respectively for the fitted Gamma distribution for population $i$.

My question is: Which methods or techniques are available for feature extraction from these varied population distributions? These extracted features would be used as exogenous variables in predicting $y$.